# Typescript - properties and index accessor at the same time

Tags: typescript

**Is there a way to use strongly typed index accessor and access properties at the same time, without repeating the properties in type annotation?**

```
let profile = profiles[profileKey];
let profile = profiles.ADMIN;
```

---

I have dictionary of key value pair defined like this:

```
const profiles = {
    "ADMIN": "Admin",
    "TCA": "Test Center Admin",
    "TT": "Test Taker",
};
```

now properties of profiles const are infered and I can write `let admin = profiles.ADMIN`.

BUT in order to use index acessor I have to explicitely specify it:

```
const profiles: {[profileKey: string]: string} = {
    "ADMIN": "Admin",
    "TCA": "Test Center Admin",
    "TT": "Test Taker",
};
```

However, now I can't access properties.

I know I can define all the properties in the profiles` type annotation:

```
interface IProfiles {
   [profileKey: string]: string;
   ADMIN: string,
   TCA: string,
   TT: string,
}
```

but this is just repeating myself. Properties could be inferred, just like when I don't specify any annotation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Properties could be inferred. Is this possible

TypeScript doesn't infer what are possible values of the string `profileKey`:

```
Object.keys(profiles).map(profileKey =>
```

Technical detail: this is because of the definition of `Object.keys` function.

So `profileKey` is just some string (not limited to the three values) so TypeScript cannot apply the constraint of this key - that value. If you want to provide a constraint for all strings you have to provide the indexer definition

Comment: I don't expect to infer prossible values of profileKey, but possible properties, (`profiles.ADMIN`, `profiles. TCA` and `profiles.TT`). I can use these properties as long as I don't specify index accessor.